# What would be implementation GetHashCode() for IEqualityComparer<double>

Tags: c#, .net, hashcode

I am looking for simple implementation of `GetHashCode()` method for following class.

```
public class EpsilonEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<double>
{
    private readonly double _epsilon;
    public EpsilonEqualityComparer(double epsilon)
    {
        _epsilon = epsilon;
    }

    public bool Equals(double x, double y)
    {
        return Math.Abs(x - y) < _epsilon;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(double obj)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Of course trivial implementation would be something like `return Math.Sign(obj)`. Nevertheless I am looking for something more practical. Do you have any idea?

Comment: This may not be easy. `GetHashCode()` is supposed to act consistently with respect to `Equals()`. If your `Equals()` compares against epsilon, then two doubles that compare equal against epsilon *must* have the same hash code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This breaks the specification of `IEqualityComparer<>` even before you have to worry about `GetHashCode`.

For an equality check, you need `x == y && y == z` to imply `x == z` but this is not true for your `Equals` implementation. For example, with an epsilon of `1`, you have `1 == 1.9` and `1.9 == 2.8` but not `1 == 2.8`.

(You also require `x == x`, and `x == y` to imply `y == x`, but your equality check is fine with those.)

Answer (score 6):

I am afraid my answer to this will be analoguous to this: [How to implement GetHashCode for this situation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25524127/how-to-implement-gethashcode-for-this-situation/25524606#25524606)

However in your case the situation is not so obvious. It looks like you have a properly defined equality condition, but it  might not be.

In the other answer I referred to MSDN stating:

> (x.Equals(y) && y.Equals(z)) returns true if and only if x.Equals(z) returns true.

Now, say you have three numbers:

```
x = anything
y = x + epsilon
z = y + epsilon // == x + 2 * epsilon
```

Then `x.Equals(y)` and `y.Equals(z)` but `x` does not equal `z`.

Because of that you won't end up with properly defined distinct equality sets, and you can't assign those sets any hashcode numbers.

Comment: Shame that I cannot accept two answers. Anyway thank you guys.